# Messages open automatically at random times on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages

My early 2014 MacBook air randomly opens Messages by itself. I don't remember setting something up or changing a setting that causes my MacBook to do this. I am logged into Messages, which is synced to my iPad messages, but it doesn't just open when I get a notification, it's completely random.

I don't want to delete Messages or log out of it because I still use it sometimes. I just want Messages to stop opening automatically. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @bmike's help and a bit of troubleshooting, I figured out the cause is from receiving a message from a do-not-disturb group chat. Logging in and out of Messages solves this problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don’t want to sign out, it’s the fastest way to diagnose this. Make a log of how often you catch it launching - and once you know how long it takes for 10 launches - sign out for that time.

Then if it launches in that time interval, you know it’s launching locally. If you never get a launch, you know it’s messages coming in that launch the app.

Until you know if it’s a push notification or a local event launching it, you’ll have a hard time diagnosing either cause.

Comment: Shouldn't the first word of your third paragraph be "Unless" ?

Comment: I’m an optimist @DavidSupportsMonica and unless works splendidly as well. Thank you very much for the close reading and correction.

Comment: S'funny. I just came back to this, and your original wording seems perfectly apt. I don't know what kind of burr I had under the saddle here.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, it used to be "when", but doesn't matter now. **bmike**, I logged the times Messages opened, and it seems to happen sometimes when I get a message. I tested with a group chat in DND, and another without DND. I don't know what other factors I may need to test, but it seems to still happen randomly. I'm trying to see if Messages still opens when I'm signed out now.

Comment: @bmike, It seems that my messages sometimes open when I get a message in a DND group chat. Messages does not open when I am logged out.

Comment: Put up an answer @existingperson sometimes the simplest thing is overlooked. Well done.